# How do I take the value of textfield along with the href value to the next page using Ajax in java web app?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using Ajax in java web application and i want to take the value of textfield along with the href link to the next page.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
           <% String root = getServletContext().getContextPath();
           %>
              <table  border="0" id="box-table-b">
                  <thead><tr>
                  <th height="31" colspan="2" nowrap>Enter User Id of Patient </th>
                      </tr></thead>
                <tr>`enter code here`
                  <td width="76" nowrap>UserId</td>
                  <td width="85"  nowrap>
                      <input type="text" name="confuserid" id="confuserid"/>
                 </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td height="66" colspan="2" align="center" valign="middle" nowrap>            
                <a href="#" onclick="returndisplayData('<%=root%>/confapp.do?method=confapp','entry');"><input type="button" value="Submit"></a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
```

Comment: Hi Maninder, welcome to Stack Overflow. You will have better luck getting an answer if you ask a question. You should explain what you want to do, what you have tried, what is not working and how it is not working.

Comment: @digitaljoel the main thing i want is that i want to get the value of this this text field like here returndisplayData('<%=root%>/confapp.do?method=confapp&confuserid=?','entry');"> i want that value at the position of question mark(?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the control and the link in a form and submit the form via GET, but that will take you away from your ajax.

Another option would be to simply get the value of the confuserid using jQuery and append it to the URL you are passing to your returndisplayData function.

something like

```
function getMyURL() {
    return '<%=root%>/confapp.do?method=confapp&confuserid='+$("#confuserid").val();
}
```

then your link looks like

```
<a href="#" onclick="returndisplayData(getMyURL(),'entry');"><input type="button" value="Submit"></a>
```

Obviously you would need to include jQuery in your page.

Comment: i dont know about the jquery so can you tell me how can i append the value to this url using jquery. thank you.

Comment: i think the problem is close to its solution. i have used this and use the alert too to check what it returns. this is showing text field value now but i didn't get the result. the alert box shows the value as <%=root%>/confapp.do?method=confapp&confuserid=Maninder . i think this is not working properly as there we need the url in the single quote. So the question is that can this value be returned as '<%=root%>/confapp.do?method=confapp&confuserid=Maninder' .

Comment: i have tried returning the url in single quote but the problem is not solved.. i am just getting the please wait that is coded in ajax.